# A simple calculator using an applet

Tags: java, calculator

I need help moving my solve code in my calculator into its own separate class.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;


public class Calculator extends Applet
{

private Label calculatorL; //Sets the label
private boolean firstDigit = true; //Sets Boolean firstDigit to be true
private float savedValue = 0.0f;//Sets saved value to 0
private String operator = "="; //Sets Default operator

public void init ()
{

    setLayout (new BorderLayout()); //Sets the layout

    add ("North", calculatorL = new Label ("0", Label.RIGHT));

    Panel calculatorPanel = new Panel(); //Adding a panel for the buttons
    calculatorPanel.setLayout (new GridLayout (4, 4)); 
    calculatorPanel.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
    calculatorPanel.setForeground(Color.BLUE);

    addButtons (calculatorPanel, "123-");
    addButtons (calculatorPanel, "456*");
    addButtons (calculatorPanel, "789/");
    addButtons (calculatorPanel, ".0=+");

    add("Center", calculatorPanel);

}

public boolean action (Event event, Object inputobject)
{
    if (event.target instanceof Button)
    {
        String inputstring = (String)inputobject;
        if ("0123456789.".indexOf (inputstring) != -1)
        {
            if (firstDigit)
            {
                firstDigit = false;
                calculatorL.setText (inputstring);
            }
            else
            {
                calculatorL.setText(calculatorL.getText() + inputstring);
            }
        }  
        else
        {
            if(!firstDigit)
            {
                solve(calculatorL.getText());
                firstDigit = true;
            }
            operator = inputstring;
        }

        return true;

        }
        return false;

    }

    public void solve (String valueToBeComputed)
    {
        float sValue = new Float (valueToBeComputed).floatValue();
        char c = operator.charAt (0);
        switch (c)
        {
            case '=': savedValue = sValue;
                break;

            case '+': savedValue += sValue;
                break;

            case '-': savedValue -= sValue;
                break;

            case '*': savedValue *= sValue;
                break;

            case '/': savedValue /= sValue;
                break;
        }

        calculatorL.setText (Float.toString(savedValue));
    }

    public void addButtons (Panel panel, String labels)
    {
        int count = labels.length();

        for (int i = 0; i<count; i ++)
        {
            panel.add (new Button (labels.substring(i,i+1)));
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: Also, I don't think asking us to refactor your code is on-topic here. You could look at the numerous other calculators in Java on this site and elsewhere for guidance and inspiration.

Comment: @BCdotWEB Im not asking you to do it, im just looking for help. To teach me how to move it into its own class.

Comment: @BCdotWEB: *" im just looking for help. To teach me how to move it into its own class"* without mor Information about your developement environment the only answer can be: **copy the relevant part to a public method in a new class.**

Comment: @BCdotWEB: before you even start to refactor you should create UnitTest which will tell you that you did not break the desired behavior of your code.

Comment: @TimothyTruckle What kind of other information are you looking for?

Comment: @DylanBassett: especially: what IDE do you use? most have support for refactorings like this. If we know the IDE we can point to the right menu entries and wizards.

Comment: @TimothyTruckle How do we set up unit test?

Comment: @TimothyTruckle I just use programmers notepad, pretty basic one. Do you know any that are good at refactoring?

Comment: start by reading a book on unit tests e.g.: https://www.amazon.com/Art-Unit-Testing-examples/dp/1617290890/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1477563756&sr=8-1&keywords=the+art+of+unit+testing

Comment: @DylanBassett: I use eclipse, but there are also netbeans, IntelliJ, JDeveloper and some more I can't recall at the moment.

Comment: @TimothyTruckle Would you recommend using eclipse

Comment: @DylanBassett: I'm used to is, so: yes. But others may prefer another IDE. Since you're developping a Web-App, I've heared that intelliJ were better on this then eclipse. At the and you have to decide yourself by comparing the feature lists...

Comment: @TimothyTruckle Im installing eclipse now

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JZn4hlMvP60  http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/moveMethod.html

Comment: @TimothyTruckle Is there anything bad about using superclasses?

Comment: @DylanBassett: *"Is there anything bad about using superclasses?"* yes. but this question cannot be answered here. In short: one of the OO principles is **"favour composition over inheritance"**